# parse.com cloud code GET function with parameters?

Tags: parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I'm writing a cloud code function in parse and I'm trying to figure out how to handle parameters in the GET url.

So I have a simple function like this:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("someFunction", function(request, response) {
    //  how can I use GET parameters here??

});
```

How to I rename the `"someFunction"` to handle GET parameters so I can use them in my cloud code function logic?

so for example I want to be able to pass in a name string: `"myName"` in the GET

https://api.parse.com/1/functions/someFunction?**name=myName**

Any simple example? I searched for a while I couldn't find one.

Thank you

EDIT:
So I modified my function to look like this:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("someFunction", function(request, response) {
    //  how can I use GET parameters here??

    var name = request.params.name

    response.success("the name = " + name)
});
```

then I call it like this:
https://api.parse.com/1/functions/someFunction?name=someName

what I get back is this:

```
{"result":"the name = **undefined**"}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Cloud Functions are called with a POST request, not a GET request. Here is a simple example for cURL I took from the documentation [1].

```
curl -X POST \
  -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: YOUR_APP_ID" \
  -H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: YOUR_REST_API_KEY" \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -d '{"name":"John Doe"}' \
  https://api.parse.com/1/functions/someFunction
```

[1] https://www.parse.com/docs/cloud_code_guide#functions

Answer (score 0):

try calling the Cloud from JS layer...

```
Parse.initialize(appId, jsId);

p =  Parse.Cloud.run('someFunc', {"name":refToName}).then(function(result) {
```